# WPF application is not show on front after using createprocess to launch

Tags: wpf, launch, createprocess

I used win32 API CreateProcess im MFC project to launch WPF application, it can success. But the question is that WPF application is not show on front of windows. If launched win32 execute program, it can show front ground.

Should I do something in WPF appliction code?
Thank you advance.

Following code is to launch application:

```
STARTUPINFO         StartInfo = { 0 };
PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcInfo = { 0 };

ZeroMemory( &StartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
StartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
StartInfo.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;    

ret = CreateProcess( NULL, lpszCmdLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &StartInfo, &ProcInfo );
if ( ret) {
    CloseHandle( ProcInfo.hThread );
    CloseHandle( ProcInfo.hProcess );
}
```

Comment: Can you attach your WPF main window XAML? And why do you need to launch it using win32 API?

Comment: Because my win32 program is running on Toolbars. And WPF application is another program. I need to launch WPF App when user clicks the icon which is on win32 program.

Comment: If that's your case, you can use another win32 library:
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.showwindow to bring it to topmost. Also this will be interesting: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowPos